# To much recursion?

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I have a problem with this code. The script generate somewhere a 'too much recursing loop'.

The script is correctly loading the data by AJAX, but it runs in a loop says the JavaScript debugger?

```
    <script>
  function init_map() {
//var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.1238433333,5.18094166667);
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

// Marker plaatsen in het midden, daarna wordt hij verplaatst naar juiste plek.
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Treinstel: 2203'
});


marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});


  } 
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);

  function getCoords() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "api.php",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false, 
    data: {
        action : "trainset",
        number : '2203'
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(returnedData) {
        var jsondata = jQuery.parseJSON(returnedData);
          //console.log(returnedData);
          var coords = jsondata.Latitude+','+jsondata.Longitude;
          //console.log('Lat: '+jsondata.Latitude);
          var coordsArray = coords.split(",");
          moveMarkerMap(coordsArray[0], coordsArray[1]);
          setTimeout(getCoords, 5000);
    },
    done: function(data) {
        //setTimeout(getCoords, 5000); // hier werkt hij niet.
    }   
     }); 
}

function moveMarkerMap(lat,lon) {
    var newLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    map.panTo(newLatLang);
    marker.setPosition(newLatLang);
}      


  //setInterval(getCoords, 10000);

$(document).ready(function(){
    getCoords();
}); 
</script>
```

The AJAX-request with the JSON-formatted string, which is correct:

{"2203":{"DateGPS":"2017-10-22T21:10:29+02:00","DateReceived":"2017-10-22T21:10:29.917+02:00","Longitude"
:5.90089,"Latitude":51.98514,"Speed":0,"DOP":0,"VehicleNumber":"2203","VehicleType":"Train A"
,"TrainNumber":"1234"}}

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Well, the biggest issue you solved yourself by not looping using setInterval. I thought I saw you add event listeners over and over again, but I may be mistaken

Comment: The debugger should show the call stack, which will let you know where the problem comes from, or at least provide information you should share.

Comment: The recursive loop redirects in the ddebugger to: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&sensor=false?
Is there something wrong at Google?

And then there is some strange thing while debugging:
When api.php is blank and empty. The Google Map is loading fine and correctly without (and offcourse using the 0,0 coords in the sea) recursing loop errors.

How come?

Comment: In a stack overflow situation, it’s not the last call the issue, it’s the sequence. Hint: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);`

Comment: I'm debugging this, and this is the problem:
var coords = jsondata.Latitude+','+jsondata.Longitude;

These are undefined? But... they exists in the AJAX response?

Comment: Problem is tackled. There was a unneeded key in the JSON-string / object.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the time interval in the success function of your AJAX call.

```
setTimeout(getCoords, 5000);
```

Once the AJAX is called. An event is registered by the "setTimeout" after a 5 seconds time. So actually after 5 seconds again AJAX is called and again function(getCoords) is registered and this goes on. So, you need to control this "setTimeout" event registration by some condition that satisfies your program logic.

Comment: I need to use a setInterval?